# Unexpected Null Pointer exception in testing

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

i am writing a unit test of a rest service in apex

My Test Class is

```
global class Feedpost9 {

    // your methods here...

    static testMethod void testRest() {
        // set up the request object
        System.RestContext.request = new RestRequest();
        RestContext.request.requestURI = '/v.9/notifications/preferences/ritesh';
        // Invoke the method directly
        Member__c member=new Member__c(name='ritesh');
        insert member;

        Notification_Settings__c no=new Notification_Settings__c(member__c=member.Id);
         no.Event__c='Category|Cloud Foundry' ;
         no.Event_Per_Member__c='12';
         insert no;


        NotificationRestService.retrievingNotificationSettings();

        RestContext.request.requestURI = '/v.9/notifications/preferences' ;

        NotificationRestService.retrievingNotificationSettings();
        RestContext.request.requestURI ='/v.9/notifications/preferences/ritesh.xml';
NotificationRestService.retrievingNotificationSettings();
    }
}
```

when test unit reach at this point then i got an error
 RestContext.request.requestURI = '/v.9/notifications/preferences' ;

```
        NotificationRestService.retrievingNotificationSettings();
```

error is

System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Class.NotificationRestService.retrievingNotificationSettings: line 46, column 1 Class.Feedpost9.testRest: line 23, column 1

and the segment where i am getting this error is

```
 List<Notification_Settings__c> note1=[SELECT id,name,Member__r.name,Do_not_Notify__c,Event__c,Event_Per_Member__c,Notification_Method__c from Notification_Settings__c WHERE Member__r.name= :userName Limit 1];
Notification_Settings__c note;

if(note1 !=null )
{if(note1.size() >0)
note=note1.get(0);
}
```

and error is on the line {if(note1.size() >0)
i am unable to figure if note1 is not equal to null then it will come to next line but in next line it is giving me error why note1 is null in next linel and passing first if statement.query should return empty list .please someone help!!

Comment: Really weird, I have no idea how it can pass first if but throw null pointer exception on second one. Are you sure the error message points to the second if's line?

Comment: Yes, I agree. A list from any query will always return a non null list. If no elements, it is just size 0. I think there is something more than just a NRE here. In my last project I remember getting an odd NRE that turned out to be an error in the code elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Ritesh Mehandiratta, My assumption is that line NotificationRestService.retrievingNotificationSettings(); makes a callout which is prohibited after insert on line insert member; I have the same problem and I don't know how to solve it ;-(

Comment: That's easy :) if you can't reorder (callout first, DML later) then read about the @future annotation and move the callout to this different context. The reason for error is that by default database can't be held up, waiting for results (up to 2 minutes) or have success of the operation dependent on this other system. It's up to you how yous tructure your code. But this should be a different question I think ;)

Comment: @future is not an option as I need new data NOW. I run createData function to create NEW account with valid ID and then I want to use this Account's ID in my tests.

Comment: You'll need to supply fake ID it for the test, sorry. Read about REST mocks, Test.isRunningTest() etc. Real callouts from SF to rest/soap endopints are forbidden in unit tests anyway, even if you'd get past this reordering issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add @isTest(SeeAllData=true) annotation

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
global class Feedpost9 {

}
```

Comment: i got ur point but see in first if statement i am checking wheather note1 is null or not it is passing and in second nested if it is throwing null pointer exception r u getting me where i am confused??